# Program to find perfect numbers

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a program that will find the first five perfect numbers. It almost works but for some reason the numbers 24 and 2016 also get mixed in. I have no idea why.
Heres the code:

```
    int perfectNums, amount = 5, tries;
    bool check;

    public void Run()
    {
        perfectNums = 0;
        
        for (int i = 1; perfectNums < amount; i++)
        {
            check = isPerfectNum(i);

            if (check == true)
            {
                perfectNums++;
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }

    }

    public static bool isPerfectNum(int num)
    {
        bool isPerfect = false;
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
            {
                sum = sum + i;
            }

            if (sum == num)
            {
                isPerfect = true;
                
            }
        }


        return isPerfect;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @TinoZ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number

Comment: Even without exactly knowing what your desired result is, I belive the `if (sum == num)` test should be outside the loop. This changes `isPerfect` to true when the condition is true for any intermeidate step.

Comment: Because you have to break the loop if the sum is greater than the number
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 + 8 = 24

Comment: Call it with 24 and step through your code to see when you should set isPerfect to false again or when to break out of the loop. What does 24/12 do for the perfectness of the number?

Comment: honestly, perfect numbers are *so rare*, that in any real application: a `switch` would be a better implementation: `static bool IsPerfectNum(int i) => i is 6 or 28 or 496 or 8182 or 33550336;` (plus 2 or 3 more if you use `long` instead of `int`)

Comment: btw, I'm pretty sure finding the 5th perfect number via dumb brute force could take days - even on a good CPU; by about 300k it is running at *about* 1000 per second for me, and *getting slower*; but let's assume it doesn't get slower: to hit 33.5M is going to take 33 thousand seconds, so: 550 minutes, or: 9 hours; in reality, it is has telescoping complexity, so: it will take *much much* longer

Comment: update: currently at 2.5M locally, and it is now taking 5s per thousand - you can see how this is going to get worse and worse and worse

Answer (score 1):

You can't deduce whether it is a perfect number until you have *finished* calculating the aliquot sum;

For example:

```cs
    public static bool IsPerfectNum(int num)
    {
        int aliquotSum = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
            {   // is a divisor
                aliquotSum += i;
            }
        }

        return aliquotSum == num;
    }
```

(you could also probably half the number of tests - there won't be any divisors above `num/2`)

Answer (score 0):

The check:

```
if (sum == num)
{
  isPerfect = true;       
}
```

should be outside the loop, at the bottom of your method; otherwise at a certain iteration you would get 1+2+3+4+6+8=24 but you are still processing, and the final check would have been 1+2+3+4+6+8+12!=24.
Btw, I agree to just debug your code step by step in order to get the faulty part.

Comment: The check definitely should not be outside the loop if you don't want to burn millions of clock cycles for nothing. Fail fast and all.

Comment: I agree with you, but many performance aspects are missing in the code (for example checking the divisors up to half the target number)

Comment: @CodeCaster given that perfect numbers are pretty rare, the number of times short-circuiting on *success* would matter is vanishingly small; it is *almost always* going to run to completion *anyway* (and return `false`); see also: my comment in the question about using a `switch`

Comment: @Marc of course, didn't think about this enough.